# Цвет в базе или от класса? Какой из этих вариантов лучше?

Tags: php, css, design

Стоит следующая задача, менять цвет сайта в зависимости от категории. Без возможности менять цвет в админке.

Есть идея генерить для категории класс типо, category1-class. И заранее в css чтоб мы имели такое:

```
category1-class {
   .bg-primary{
        background: black;
   }
   .bg-secondary{
        background: white;
   }
}

category2-class {
   .bg-primary{
        background: green;
   }
   .bg-secondary{
        background: gray;
   }
}
```

и т.д.

Второй вариант хранить primary, secondary цвет в базе в отдельных столбцах для каждой категории. И при выводе страницы на беке вставлять вот так (соответственно вместо цвета будет подставляться значение из базы).

[image: Второй вариант]

Какой вариант по-вашему лучше?

Спасибо.

Comment: Какой удобнее, тот и лучше. Имхо.